# How do I use this type of semi-open wood burning fireplace? Is it any good for providing heat, or is it really just decorative?

Tags: fireplace

So we have a fireplace, but have never had any real intention of using it. The previous owner managed to burn several holes in the carpet and surrounding mantle, which has further convinced us that compared to grid heat it's just not worth it. It should be noted, that when we moved in, the glass doors were not present (I guess maybe the previous owners broke the original ones?) and these are replacements we got from amazon to keep the heat/cool in.

That said, given the possibility of rolling blackouts, I'm realizing it might come to using it. Problem is, I have no idea of if I'm supposed to close the doors, the metal curtains, both, etc etc. about all I know is the little metal door at the top needs to open to allow heat to escape.

[image]

Comment: With a close up we can’t tell there could be heatalators or air Chanel’s built into the brick work. 

There are also grates that have tubes that can be added and I even found a neat water heater / heat exchanger for a fireplace in the past. A small fan turned a decorative fireplace into a real heat source. If you burn long enough the brick work will warm up but it’s not very efficient. Adding a wood stove insert I have heated a 3000 sf house so there are possibilities.

Comment: Either clean or have someone clean chimney first.  Windows can be open when heating, but keep metal curtains close, they keep sparks from escaping.  Use dry wood, not green.  If name/make of fireplace known, use google, looks manufactored.

Comment: @crip659 I have a chimney sweep in the attic, is cleaning the chimney as simple is running the brush through the flue until soot/Ash stops falling out?

Comment: Basically, just to make sure no build up of cesote in chimney pipes from top of roof to fireplace.  Also a check of pipes are in good order, no leakes/defects.  Do not need chimney fire or smoke in house when trying to keep warm.  Fireplace does look like it can provide nice heat, at least to part of house.

Comment: I would suggest you have a professional check and clean the chimney at least the first time. If it wasn't properly maintained by the previous owner there could be considerable soot buildup. Carbon glazed unto the flue could ignite. Chimney fires are no fun.

Comment: To tell the truth that looks like it has had very little use. Not much to doing a sweep but if they have the additional training they can inspect also